# Enterprise Library 4.0: How to get rid of headers and footers when using a Rolling Flat File Trace Listener

Tags: logging, header, enterprise-library, footer

As the title already says, is there a way to get rid of the headers and footers that are placed before and after each log entry when using a Rolling Flat File Trace Listener?

Although I cleared the "Header" and "Footer" properties the log file still shows an empty line before and after each log entry.

**Update**

Here you can see the config file I use.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="CheckLoignWebService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <loggingConfiguration name="Logging Application Block" tracingEnabled="true"
    defaultCategory="CheckLoginWebService" logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="true">
    <listeners>
      <add source="Enterprise Library Logging" formatter="Text Formatter"
        log="Application" machineName="" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        traceOutputOptions="None" filter="All" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        name="Formatted EventLog TraceListener" />
      <add fileName="loginWSTest.log" footer="" formatter="SimpleTextFormatter"
        header="" rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment" rollInterval="Day"
        rollSizeKB="0" timeStampPattern="yyyy-MM-dd" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        traceOutputOptions="None" filter="All" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add template="{timestamp}{tab}[{severity}]{tab}{message}" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        name="SimpleTextFormatter" />
      <add template="Timestamp: {timestamp}&#xD;&#xA;Message: {message}&#xD;&#xA;Category: {category}&#xD;&#xA;Priority: {priority}&#xD;&#xA;EventId: {eventid}&#xD;&#xA;Severity: {severity}&#xD;&#xA;Title:{title}&#xD;&#xA;Machine: {machine}&#xD;&#xA;Application Domain: {appDomain}&#xD;&#xA;Process Id: {processId}&#xD;&#xA;Process Name: {processName}&#xD;&#xA;Win32 Thread Id: {win32ThreadId}&#xD;&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}&#xD;&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}&#xD;&#xA;)}"
        type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        name="Text Formatter" />
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="CheckLoginWebService">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events" />
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category" />
      <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Formatted EventLog TraceListener" />
        </listeners>
      </errors>
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
  <applicationSettings>
    <CheckLoignWebService.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="CheckLoignWebService_CNLoginWS_CampusNet_Login" serializeAs="String">
        <value>********************</value>
      </setting>
    </CheckLoignWebService.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post your configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

I used your listener and formatter with the EL Logging Quickstart.  The messages are logged without any empty lines before or after.

```
3/15/2010 5:10:47 PM    [Information]   asdaf
3/15/2010 5:10:58 PM    [Information]   22
3/15/2010 5:11:05 PM    [Information]   dfas
```

Is it possible that your message contains new line character(s) that are causing the empty lines?

Comment: Mh, I will check this again. Thanks for you help so far.

Comment: @Flo - Just curious if you found anything?